# OpenID in backend REST API

Tags: api, rest, openid

We are designing a web service for an application that takes OpenID as an authentication option.  The question came up how do we enable API access for this user at a later time?

For clarity here is an example:

1) user A visits the site and registers using Yahoo (or other) OpenID
2) at a later time we'd like to enable API access to backend synchronization apps that act on behalf of this user.
3) giving an app a key that can access all accounts everywhere is not an option for security reasons

What are examples of using patterns like that?

Comment: How is this related to OpenID?

Comment: @thebjorn - It's using OpenID in an API - an API design question.

Comment: yes, I understand that you're using OpenID from your question... however, after "user A visits the site and registers using an OpenID provider" I'm assuming that you store this fact in your user database..?  ..probably the same way that you would if you'd implemented regular username/password registration?

Comment: @thebjorn that's true we would save the OpenID information but what's the pattern to verify that the OpenID is still valid at a later time? It sounds like without interactive browser session OpenID doesn't have a way to verify that it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard OpenID requires a browser because it depends on being able to load a page from a foreign site to complete the signin process. Therefore it's not appropriate for server-to-server API use.

It is more common to use [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) as an authentication mechanism for server-to-server APIs. While standard OAuth also requires a browser and a user-interactive flow to grant access to a new application, it results in a token that can then be used by the application to act on behalf of the user for user-unattended requests.

Facebook is possibly the most high-profile user of OAuth 2 for APIs, and its [Login Architecture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/) document describes the various login flows they support at a high level. The one titled "Server-side Login" is the conventional OAuth flow, while others are different approaches that support different use-cases like mobile app sign-in and access from client-side JavaScript embedded on other sites.